# how to move dataframe's one column names(hierarchical) to index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sorry this seems a basic manipulation but I can't figure it out after searching. The title is probably not accurate.

I have this dataframe

```
Bunker Port   Rotterdam   Singapore  ...   Rotterdam   Singapore
bunker             HSFO        HSFO  ...       VLSFO       VLSFO
period                               ...                        
Jul 23       453.318000  461.028000  ...  518.098000  553.426000
Aug 23       448.266000  454.016000  ...  513.596000  549.716000
```

There are 2 levels for the column names: 'Bunker Port' and 'bunker'

and I wish to convert the df to below(the 0-4 index is unecessary):

```
                   bunker     HSFO        MGO    VLSFO
0     period  Bunker Port      NaN        NaN      NaN
1     Jul 23    Rotterdam  453.318  723.83300  518.098
2     Aug 23    Rotterdam  448.266  735.00000  513.596
3     Jul 23    Singapore  461.028  734.04850  553.426
4     Aug 23    Singapore  454.016  738.74945  549.716
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `df.stack(level=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `stack()` function to move the `Bunker Port` column index as a row index and then you can use `reset_index()` function to reset the index and convert the MultiIndex levels into separate columns.

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

You can also specify the level inside the `stack()` function:

```
df.stack(level=[0, 1]).reset_index()
```